# Ratio of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I have observed the following property:
If $F_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number and $F_1=1; F_2=1$
Then $\frac{F_{2n+1}}{F_{2n}}>\phi$
And $\frac{F_{2n}}{F_{2n-1}}<\phi$
For all natural numbers n.
How do I prove this?
Here $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Comment: try using the fact that $F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt(5)}$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio and $\psi=1-\phi$

Comment: @temp thank you that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:You can use the general form of the fibonnaci sequence

$$
F_n={({1+\sqrt{5}\over2})^n-({1-\sqrt{5}\over2})^n\over\sqrt{5}}={\phi^n-(-{1\over\phi})^n\over\sqrt{5}}
$$